# Vertical Submenu not lining up with the Horizontal Main Menu

Tags: html, css, menu

To begin with, I am new to HTML and CSS, as in, two weeks ago, I knew what a webpage was and that was it. I've been asked to help design a website, so I've been learning as much as possible. I've come to an issue that seems to be fairly common, but I can't seem to get it to work, no matter what modifications I try.

I have a horizontal main menu with a vertical submenu on click. I managed to get the vertical menu to function almost perfectly, except for two problems; the submenu does not appear under the parent item, and the submenu extends into the element below.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="header">
<img id="logo" src="../images/Logo.jpg">
<a href="# src="../images/fblink.jpg"></a>
<a href="#><img id="lilink" src="../images/lilink.jpg"></a>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../index.htm">Home</a></li>
   <li id="current">About Us
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/#">Person 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Person 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Person 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="../News_Events/Main.htm">News and Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="../Financial_Resources/Main.htm">Financial Resources</a></li>
   <li><a href="../Market_View/Main.htm">Market View</a></li>
   <li><a href="../Services/Main.htm">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="../Contact_Us/Contact.htm">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  </div>
```

The CSS is

```
#menu {background-color:#DAE2EA;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       padding-right:.75em;
       clear:left;
       }

#menu ul {list-style:none;
          text-align:right;
          position:relative;
          }

#menu ul li {display:inline;
             border-right:double 2px #33495F;
             border-radius:0 0 3em 3em;
             padding: 0 .75em 0 2em;
             text-decoration:none;
             color:#78AEE6;
             font-size:1.2em;
             }

#menu a {text-decoration:none;
         color:#78AEE6;
         }

#menu a:visited {color:#78AEE6;
                 font-size:1.2em;
                 }

#menu a:hover {font-size:1.25em;
               }

#current {font-size:1.5em;
          font-weight:bold;
          }

#menu ul li ul {position:absolute;
                }

#menu ul li ul li {margin-left:.5em;
                   font-size:.85em;
                   display:block;
                   text-align:right;
                   font-weight:normal;
                   border:none;
                   }
```

This shows the page once the link is clicked. What happens though, is that the About Us submenu shows up under the Home link, and the Nav element doesn't extend to cover the submenu, so Person 1, 2, and 3 all overlay the main element (coding for other areas not included).

I know that I'm new, so this is probably a very simple fix. I appreciate your patience and thank you in advance for the help. I also apologize if the coding is not quite correct.

As a side note, I have no JS or Jquery skills yet, so please help me keep this to HTML5 and CSS3 for the time being.

Regards,
 Tom Stone.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still learning. Would you please enlighten me as to what a "fiddle" is?

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and make your code working, save the code and post the link here. So that some one will help.

Comment: Oh! Excellent, thank you very much.

The fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/q7PAH/

Comment: As per my understanding, you're looking for something similar to this [example](http://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/). Hope it helps!